# how does your add to fullcalendar Works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I took your fullCalendar script but can't make date disabling working. Do i need to just add

```
"minDate":"+1d"
```

like jqueryUi in the initialisation of the fullcalendar or is an other way to get this worked.

I want to disable the dates before the current day on a full calendar that only use monthly view and selectable range dates. Does your fix work for this case .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is not implemented yet. here is the feature request:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=158